# Regex to replace BETWEEN SQL operator with AND

Tags: c#, regex

I have SQL Where clause to run on DataView, but C# DataView does not accept BETWEEN operator. I need to convert any BETWEEN operator in query string to And, example:

**Before:** Year BETWEEN 2010 and 2014

**After:** Year >= 2010 and Year <= 2014

I tried this pattern

```
$.+ BETWEEN .+ AND .+/
```

But it didn't work, also not replacing anything so far

Comment: Tried `.Replace("BETWEEN", "AND")`?

Comment: Could you post your code you need help with?

Comment: It's a string to manipulate with regex replace. I gave example in the post.

Comment: woah there - you need to be *really* careful with regex; `BETWEEN .+ AND .+` could replace some very different scenarios, including the AND in a WHERE clause

Comment: "I tried this pattern" - showing us just  the match pattern (which doesn't actually have any replacement groups to start with) isn't really enough - we'd need to see the entire usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *works*, but I think you would do better to write a query that matches the required syntax...

```
var sql = "blah Year BETWEEN 2010 and 2014 blah";
var munged = Regex.Replace(sql,
    @"\s([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)\s+BETWEEN\s+([0-9]+)\s+and\s+([0-9]+)\s",
    " $1 >= $2 and $1 <= $3 ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Note that I'm limiting the handling here to integers; expanding it to cope with strings is much more complex.